# What are the conditions SonarQube says are uncovered?

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

SonarQube says there are uncovered conditions on all the arguments to the constructors for every component in my angular project (as well as anything decorated with `@Input()`)

What are the conditions it's referring to, and how would I go about covering them? All arguments are provided by the DI framework.

Example:

[image: SQ says there are uncovered conditions for each argument to this constructor]

No one at my job knows what's going on here and my google-fu has failed. Something tells me these conditions are not worth covering at all, so an alternative acceptable solution would be just a way to turn this check off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the "conditions" being referred to here represent the various permutations of constructor values being present and not present.  The fact that you say that "All arguments are provided by the DI framework" means that this is only ever called with all the property values supplied.  Are you able to call the constructor with some of the values not being provided?  Each one of those permutations where one of the values is NOT provided will represent one of those missing conditions.

Comment: i assumed the same thing, but that seemed like a completely pointless condition to cover. our application has no logic to handle instances of those parameters not being present, because: What would you even do in that situation?; Such code would be bloaty; If such a thing occurred, then you'd have far greater problems than some unit tests not passing.

Comment: The moral of this is that increasing code coverage is generally a good thing, but reaching 100% is not.